# How can certain choices of sets $\mathbb {S}$ produce paradoxes?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

**Preface**: I am not a mathematician, and I don't have any knowledge of measure theory. If this question requires too much knowledge to answer directly I'd be happy if you would point me in the right direction.

I am currently reading "Deep Learning" by Ian Goodfellow, and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville. Section 3.12 describe technical details of contiuous variables. Here they say that the probability of a continuous vector-valued $x$ lying in some set $\mathbb{S}$ is given by the integral of $ p(x)$. Here they mention that some choices of this set S can produce paradoxes.

How can the sets $\mathbb{S}_1$ and $\mathbb{S}_2$ produce paradoxes if they are defined as follows?

$p(x\in\mathbb{S}_1) + (x\in\mathbb{S}_2)  > 1$ but $\mathbb{S}_2 \cap \mathbb{S}_2 = \emptyset$

How does the infinite precision of real numbers come into play here? How can fractal-shaped sets or sets that are defined  by transforming the set of rational numbers cause this paradox?

Does this mean that fractals hold no place in probability theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get concrete.

Consider the interval $[0, 1]$. We consider two points $x, y$ on the interval to be "equivalent" if $x - y$ is a rational number.

The "equivalence class" of $x$ is the set of all $y$ s.t. $y$ is equivalent to $x$. That is, $Equiv(x) = \{y \in [0, 1] : x - y$ is rational$\}$. Note that $Equiv(x) = Equiv(y)$ iff $x = y$.

Now consider the collection of all equivalence classes $S = \{Equiv(x) : x \in [0, 1]\}$. Each equivalence class has an element (in particular, $x \in Equiv(x)$). By the axiom of choice, we may take a function $f : S \to [0, 1]$ s.t. for every $x$, $f(Equiv(x)) \in Equiv(x)$.

Now consider the set $J = \{f(Equiv(x)) : x \in [0, 1]\}$. And consider the uniform distribution over the set $[-1, 2]$. What is $P(x \in J)$?

I claim that $P(x \in J)$ cannot be zero. For consider sets of the form $J_q = \{j + q : j \in J\}$, where $q$ is a rational number s.t. $-1 \leq 1$. It can be demonstrated that $[0, 1] \in \bigcup\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}, -1 \leq q \leq 1} J_q$ and that $J_q, J_{q'}$ are disjoint whenever $q \neq q'$. Therefore, $P(x \in [0, 1]) = 1/3 \leq P(x \in \bigcup\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}, -1 \leq q \leq 1} J_q) = \sum\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}, -1 \leq q \leq 1} P(x \in J_q)$. Since $J_q$ is just a translation of $J$ and we're dealing with a uniform distribution, it must be the case that $P(x \in J_q) = P(x \in J)$. Then we have $1/3 \leq \sum\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}, -1 \leq q \leq 1} P(x \in J_q) = \sum\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}, -1 \leq q \leq 1} P(x \in J)$.

But if $P(x \in J) = 0$, then we would have $1/3 \leq 0$; this is a contradiction. Then $P(x \in J) > 0$.

But in that case, we would have $P(x \in \bigcup\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}, -1 \leq q \leq 1} J_q) = \sum\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}, -1 \leq q \leq 1} P(x \in J) = \infty$, since we're adding up infinitely many of the same positive value. This, too, is a contradiction.

Thus, the only sensible thing to do is say that $P(x \in J)$ is undefined. This illustrates the principle that we must carefully consider for what $J$ the statement $P(x \in J)$ is defined. Careful analysis of these considerations lead mathematicians to the notion of a $\sigma$ algebra.

This construction is known as the "Vitali Set construction".